# issues when I use tablayout and viewpager inside fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi I have a TabLayout and ViewPager inside a fragment

```C#
public class Explore : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, AppCompatActivity
    {
        private TabLayout tablayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TimeBuget timeBuget;
        private SpecialActivity specialActivity;
        public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

            //return base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExploreLayout,container,false);

            viewPager = View.FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.viewpagerExplore);
            setupViewPager (viewPager);

            tablayout = View.FindViewById<TabLayout> (Resource.Id.sliding_tabsExplore);
            tablayout.SetupWithViewPager (viewPager);
        }

        private void InditialFragment()
        {
            timeBuget = new TimeBuget ();
            specialActivity = new SpecialActivity ();
        }
        public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            InditialFragment ();
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter (SupportFragmentManager);
            adapter.addFragment (timeBuget, "Explore");
            adapter.addFragment (specialActivity, "Featured");

            viewPager.Adapter=adapter;
        }
    }
```

1. Classes cannot have multiple base classes.
2. If I don't use AppCompatActivity so I can't use SupportFragmentManager

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to host the fragment inside the activity, not use both at the same time. After you do that you could access the `SupportFragmentManager` like this:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter ((SpecialActivity as AppCompatActivity).SupportFragmentManager);
```

Comment: (MainActivity as AppCompatActivity).SupportFragmentManager). Project.MainActivity' is a `type' but a `variable' was expected

Comment: THis fragment lies inside viewpager in MainActivity.

Comment: Yeah, so instead of `SpecialActivity` you use `MainActivity`